# insert partial view after specific tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li class="comment">
    <p>comment 1</p>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="/assets/images/i/2.jpg" width="17px" height="15px">
      <a>sharok</a>
      <span>·</span>
      <span>21.12.2012 0:00:00</span>
      <span>·</span>
      <a href="#">
                    Reply</a>
      <span>·</span>
      <a href="#">Complain</a>
    </div>
    <ul> ***this is child comment
      <li class="comment">
        <ul>
          <li class="comment">
            <p>comment 1.1</p>
            <div class="info">
              <img src="/assets/images/i/2.jpg" width="17px" height="15px">
              <a>sharok</a>
              <span>·</span>
              <span>25.12.2012 0:00:00</span>
              <span>·</span>
              <a href="#">
                    Reply</a>
              <span>·</span>
              <a href="#">Complain</a>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li class="comment">

             </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want when user clicks on `Reply` link then show my partial view after `div class="info"`.

This is my partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DT.KazBilet.Objects.PublicationComment>" %>
<div class="wrap">
    <h4>Comment</h4>
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoComment", "Publication", new {id = Model.Publication.OID},new AjaxOptions()))
      {%>
    <%if(Model.ParentCommentId != null) %>
    <%=Html.Hidden("ParentCommentId", Model.ParentCommentId) %>
    <%=Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Text) %>        
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn ok_btn" />
    <%}%>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with ajax, using the `$.get` function ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ). However, you should consider simply entering your comment div straight into the HTML and hide it until a user clicks the Reply button, and then display it (sliding, fading in etc) instead of getting it from the server. Since it will be the same content every time, there's no point in getting it dynamically once a user wants to post a reply.

If you still want to get it dynamically, do something like:

```
$(".replybtn").click(function() {
    $.get('path/to/partial/view', function(data) {
        $(this).parent().after(data);
    });
});
```

You should add a class to the reply link/button, as it's hard to capture the click event on it otherwise.